# AJAX Uncaught SyntaxError Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have used ajax functions lots of times but seem to have a syntax error that has wasted a lot of my time.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'php/charge.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {  
        stripeToken: token.id //console says error here     
    }
});
```

### UPDATE:

It is part of this Stripe checkout code.

```
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'pk_test_*************',
    token: function(token) {
        //alert(token.id)-----> this worked and has a value
        $.ajax({
            url: 'php/charge.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {  
                stripeToken: token.id  
            }  
        });  
    }
});
```

Comment: I think it is `method: "POST"` instead of `type: "POST"`.

Comment: Check your code where was token declared and does it have token object has an id?

Comment: @Titus, you can use type: "POST" too http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Comment: @generalgmt A MDN link or other reputable source is almost always better than a W3Fools link http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: @generalgmt good to know, I wasn't sure about that and you're right the error occurs probably because `token` is out of scope or was never defined.

Comment: @Titus No that does not solve it.

Right above the ajax function I tried alerting token.id and it works fine. 

Update: I tried commenting out the data field and I still have an error near the end of the ajax function. #Confused

Comment: Made updates to show you all the full picture

Comment: comma after 'POST' ?

Comment: @Warpasaur Sorry I forgot to add the comma in question rather than my code.My bad it was a copy paste error. I have updated the question  accordingly

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: To add another, although Stack Overflow is not an endorsement site, to @PhpMyCoder 's list -> http://www.sitepoint.com/. SitePoint has an awesome collection of tutorials for HTML, JavaScript, CSS, you name it. Check the AJAX section out for yourself: http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript/ajax-javascript/.

Comment: @Warpasaur the OP stated in the title - what's more interesting would be which line the error appeared to be on - did the error provide a line number

Comment: @Warpasaur Uncaught SyntaxError Unexpected identifier.... its in the title.

Comment: @think123 Ya it pointed to the stripeToken: token.id   line

Comment: @think123 Even another interesting observation.... when I put all the data attribute in one line.. the console then put the error at the end of the ajax function

Comment: @alaboudi are you sure that you don't have any extra code inside your function? From what I can see, your function is properly written with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is that there is a semicolon inside your handler configuration.

Try to take out the semicolon after your ajax request, so that your code looks like this:

```
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'pk_test_*************',
    token: function(token) {
        //alert(token.id)-----> this worked and has a value
        $.ajax({
            url: 'php/charge.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {  
                stripeToken: token.id  
            }  
        })
    }
});
```